# node: relocation error: node: symbol pthread_cond_destroy, version GLIBC_2.3.2 not define in the file libpthread.so.0 with link time reference

Tags: node.js, linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to use GLIBC_2.3.2 in Redhat Linux to use nodejs node-v20.8.1-linux-x64. After spent a long time to solve out issues, I successfully installed and created the GLIBC_2.3.2 in my personal folder. However when I use this command to start the nodejs programe.

```
LD_PRELOAD=$HOME/local/glibc-2.32/lib/libpthread.so.0:$HOME/local/gcc-10.4.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6:$HOME/local/glibc-2.32/lib/libc.so.6:$HOME/local/glibc-2.32/lib/libm.so.6 node -v
```

it gives me this error

```
node: relocation error: node: symbol pthread_cond_destroy, version GLIBC_2.3.2 not define in the file libpthread.so.0 with link time reference
```

It's very strange if I grep GLIBC_2.3.2 in $HOME/local/glibc-2.32/lib/libpthread.so.0, it does exist.
Could you please suggest how to solve this? I'm not admin, so I don't have right to create any links that link to system files.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rz4b.jpg)

Comment: Thanks. I've used patchelf to solve the problem.